# Use Grunt to make DOM changes

Tags: image, responsive-design, attributes, gruntjs

So I want to use Lazysizes (lazy loading responsive images). Included in my Grunt stack is Responsive Images Extender, which outputs responsive image code (srcset) from simply including an "img" tag with a "src" attribute. Lazysizes requires the "data-srcset" attribute in replace of the "srcset" attribute, however. I added a script to my page that changes the "srcset" attributes to "data-srcset" attributes, but this isn't ideal as images are are already downloaded at runtime. It would be ideal if I could change the tags with Grunt, as there is no advantage in changing them live.

This seems like a very common thing, but I cannot find a good way to do it. String replace doesn't seem like an ideal solution, since it can cause problems if I ever use "srcset=" in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave the [grunt-responsive-images-extender](https://github.com/smaxtastic/grunt-responsive-images-extender) a major makeover and added the possibility to change the attribute name of `srcset` to anything you want (`data-srcset` in your case) via the `srcsetAttributeName` option.

Answer (score 0):

There is a grunt tans called [dom_munger](https://github.com/cgross/grunt-dom-munger). With dom_munger you can change HTML attributes and do a lot of interesting stuff; however I cannot find a way to change an attribute name to another thing. Perhapse you can have a better luck checking it.